# How do you display "chosen name" on the UI

Tags: names

My team and I trying to figure our how to best display someone's chosen/preferred name on the UI.

The problem we're trying to solve is, how do you make a distinction between legal and chosen name?

Option 1:
**Johnathan (John) Smith**

Option 2:
**Johnathan "John" Smith**

Option 3:
**Johnathan Smith** Chosen name: John

Thank you!

Comment: In which part would this show? The answer may vary depending on the context.

Answer (score 1):

Given this is the preferred name, everyone is going to have a preferred method of how their name is displayed. You could give your options as a dropdown - or you could simply have 2 fields:

```
Display name (shown on your profile/in communication with others/...)
[____________________________________]


Legal name (used for contracts)
[____________________________________]
```

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, typographic visual variables are also useful for this.

#### Inclination

Johnathan *John* Smith

#### Weight

**Johnathan** John **Smith**

#### Color

[image]

#### Family

[image]

#### Style

[image]